# There was an issue using the next ui Navbar in next.js 13

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, next.js13, nextui

```
"use client"
import {Navbar, Button, Link, Text} from "@nextui-org/react";
import {styled} from "@nextui-org/react"

const Box = styled("div", {
    boxSizing: "border-box",
});

const AcmeLogo = () => (
    <svg
        className=""
        fill="none"
        height="36"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32"
        width="36"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    >
        <rect fill="var(--secondary)" height="100%" rx="16" width="100%"/>
        <path
            clipRule="evenodd"
            d="M17.6482 10.1305L15.8785 7.02583L7.02979 22.5499H10.5278L17.6482 10.1305ZM19.8798 14.0457L18.11 17.1983L19.394 19.4511H16.8453L15.1056 22.5499H24.7272L19.8798 14.0457Z"
            fill="currentColor"
            fillRule="evenodd"
        />
    </svg>
);

export const MyNavbar = () => {
    return (
        <Box css={{
            maxW: "100%"
        }}>
            <Navbar isBordered variant="floating">
                <Navbar.Brand>
                    <AcmeLogo/>
                    <Text b color="inherit" hideIn="xs">
                        ACME
                    </Text>
                </Navbar.Brand>
                <Navbar.Content hideIn="xs" variant="highlight-rounded">
                    <Navbar.Link href="#">Features</Navbar.Link>
                    <Navbar.Link isActive href="#">Customers</Navbar.Link>
                    <Navbar.Link href="#">Pricing</Navbar.Link>
                    <Navbar.Link href="#">Company</Navbar.Link>
                </Navbar.Content>
                <Navbar.Content>
                    <Navbar.Link color="inherit" href="#">
                        Login
                    </Navbar.Link>
                    <Navbar.Item>
                        <Button auto flat as={Link} href="#">
                            Sign Up
                        </Button>
                    </Navbar.Item>
                </Navbar.Content>
            </Navbar>
        </Box>
    );
}
```

This is my MyNavbar component.

```
"use client";

import * as React from "react";
import {NextUIProvider} from "@nextui-org/react";


export function Providers({children}) {
    return (
        <NextUIProvider>
            {children}
        </NextUIProvider>
    );
}
```

This is my Providers.

```
import './globals.css'
import {Inter} from 'next/font/google'
import {MyNavbar} from "@/components/navbar";
import {Providers} from "@/app/provider";

const inter = Inter({subsets: ['latin']})


export const metadata = {
    title: 'Create Next App',
    description: 'Generated by create next app',
}

export default function RootLayout({children}) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
        <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
            <MyNavbar/>
            {children}
        </Providers>
        </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

This is my layout.

When I first opened the website, it was like this.
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aVM7.png)]

Then it will be like this.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLuXL.png)

I dont know how to solve it.

how to solve it.Enable CSS to render the interface from the beginning.

Comment: HI, I had a similar problem with styled components, in my case I solve the issue changing my import from import {styled} from 'styled-components' to import styled from 'styled-components'. Removing the brackets. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to remove the metadata and inter.classname properties from the layout.js file and add the "use client" at the top of the file. This change may resolve the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).